# convert string contains ISO 8859-1 hex characters code to UTF-8 java

Tags: java, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a string, which I believed contains some of ISO-8859-1 hex character code

```
String doc = "#xC1;o thun b#xE9; g#xE1;i c#x1ED9;t d#xE2;y xanh bi#x1EC3;n"
```

And I want to change it into this,

`Áo thun bé gái cột dây xanh biển`

I have tried this method but no luck

```
byte[] isoBytes = doc.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(new String(isoBytes, "UTF-8"));
```

What is the proper way to convert it? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Well you can check if it's converting correctly...

Comment: What is ```#xC1;o```?  Is it literally 6 Unicode characters: hash, x, C, 1, semicolon, o?   Or is it your representation in this post of something, such as a character with value 00C1?   In the latter case there should be no problem: C1 is capital-A-with-acute in both Unicode and 8859-1.

Comment: Your string consists of character references. There is no easy way to parse those with plain Java. You would need a library or write your own parser.

Comment: Well, it's not ISO 8859-1 because #x1EC3; implies >255 codepoints. It does look like HTML or XML hexadecimal numeric character entity references but with the leading & missing. In that case, the numbers would be Unicode codepoints. (You might be confusing that with ISO 8859-1 because of the similarities.) Where did this data come from? What is the format?

Comment: In fact, U+1EC3 is LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND HOOK ABOVE. See [UnicodeData.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt).

Comment: @TomBlodget - good point, I only looked at the first "#nn" occurrence!

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that the `#nnnn;` sequences are plain old Unicode character representation, I suggest the following approach.

```
class Cvt {

    static String convert(String in) {
        String str = in;
        int curPos = 0;
        while (curPos < str.length()) {
            int j = str.indexOf("#x", curPos);
            if (j < 0) // no more #x
                curPos = str.length();
            else {
                int k = str.indexOf(';', curPos + 2);
                if (k < 0) // unterminated #x
                    curPos = str.length();
                else { // convert #xNNNN;
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(j+2, k), 16);
                    char[] ch = { (char)n };
                    str = str.substring(0, j) + new String(ch) + str.substring(k+1);
                    curPos = j + 1; // after ch
                }
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    static public void main(String... args) {
        String doc = "#xC1;o thun b#xE9; g#xE1;i c#x1ED9;t d#xE2;y xanh bi#x1EC3;n";
        System.out.println(convert(doc));
    }

}
```

This is very similar to the approach of the previous answer, except for the assumption that the character is a Unicode codepoint and not an 8859-1 codepoint.

And the output is

> Áo thun bé gái cột dây xanh biển

Comment: Good approach - note that this supports the Unicode BMP (Basic Multilingual plane - code points up to 16 bits long). That's probably all that the OP needs. If you need to support the full Unicode character set, you need to UTF-16 encode the codepoint before putting it into the Java String.

Comment: Note you may want to build up the output in a StringBuikdee and only convert to String once at the end, for added efficiency

Comment: Agreed that efficiency could be improved if this is going to be frequently executed in performance-sensitive contexts rather than a one-off; I was focused on 'ease of writing' :-)  Note that my approach has expense more-or-less proportional to the number of '#x' fields in the string: if none, then there's one scan to discover that and no copying.

Comment: Note also the inadequate error handling: one ```#xHAHA;``` and it's all over for this code. Improvement left as exercise for the OP!

Answer (score 0):

There is no hex literal syntax for strings in Java. If you need to support that String format, I would make a helper function which parses that format and builds up a byte array and then parse that as ISO-8859-1.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class translate {

    private static byte[] parseBytesWithHexLiterals(String s) throws Exception {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            if (s.startsWith("#x")) {
                s = s.substring(2);
                while (s.charAt(0) != ';') {
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2), 16);
                    baos.write(i);
                    s = s.substring(2);
                }

            } else {
                baos.write(s.substring(0, 1).getBytes("US-ASCII")[0]);
            }

            s = s.substring(1);
        }

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String doc = "#xC1;o thun b#xE9; g#xE1;i c#x1ED9;t d#xE2;y xanh bi#x1EC3;n";
        byte[] parsedAsISO88591 = parseBytesWithHexLiterals(doc);
        doc = new String(parsedAsISO88591, "ISO-8859-1");

        System.out.println(doc); // Print out the string, which is in Unicode internally.

        byte[] asUTF8 = doc.getBytes("UTF-8"); // Get a UTF-8 version of the string.
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see where ASCII comes into it.  The input string is Unicode (because it's a String).  For characters that are not part of a #xNNN; sequence, just copy them across.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where the code can really obscure the requirements. The requirements are a bit uncertain but seem to be to decode a specialized Unicode character entity reference similar to HTML and XML, as documented in the comments.

It is also a somewhat rare case where the advantage of the regular expression engine outweighs any studying needed to understand the pattern language.

```
String input = "#xC1;o thun b#xE9; g#xE1;i c#x1ED9;t d#xE2;y xanh bi#x1EC3;n";

// Hex digits between "#x" and ";" are a Unicode codepoint value
String text = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(#x([0-9A-Fa-f]+);)")
    .matcher(input)
    // group 2 is the matched input between the 2nd ( in the pattern and its paired )
    .replaceAll(x -> new String(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(x.group(2), 16))));
System.out.println(text);
```

The matcher function finds candidate strings to replace that match the pattern. The replaceAll function replaces them with the calculated Unicode codepoint. Since a Unicode codepoint might be encoded as two `char` (UTF-16) values the desired replacement string must be constructed from a `char[]`.